# It is possible to override a plugin's Controller from another plugin?

Tags: grails, plugins, grails-plugin

I'm developing a plugin (MyPlugin) which combines some security functions to use it as a standard plugin for my next Grails application. It integrates the `Spring-Security-Core` and `Spring-Security-UI` plugins, and by its installation all dependencies should be installed automatically by adding the dependencies in the `BuildConfig` like: `plugins { compile: ...}`

So far everything works fine, but in MyPlugin I'm changing the behaviour of the `Spring-Security-UI` plugin (password encoding in User Domain), by overwriting the `UserController`. Executing MyPlugin leads to the expected behaviour and new Users are created using the correct Controller.

However, when installing MyPlugin in another Grails application, this behaviour fails and the original `UserController` of the `Spring-Security-Ui` plugin is used.

I tried to solve this by configuring the `dependsOn` and `loadAfter` properties in the `GrailsPlugin` file, but without any success.

Is it possible to fix this? Or is it only possible to overwrite behaviour/controllers in the main application?

Comment: what's the name of the new controller you've created? Is it `UserController` as well?

Comment: yes, in the new Grails App there is an UserController in the Spring-Security-Ui Plugin and in MyPlugin.

Answer (score 0):

Grails 2.2 has namespace for controllers 
http://grails.org/doc/2.2.0.RC1/guide/introduction.html#whatsNew22

So you can put in something like

```
def index() {
        redirect controller: 'user', action: 'list', plugin: 'springSecurity'
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i wanna let the code independent of which plugin is installed and which not.